# Error in runnig c++ code in linux after changing the name of its folder

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake

I have written a c++ program and run it in linux ubuntu. my program's name is: "find_relation_1.cpp" and this is its cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(find_relation_1)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED) 
find_package(Qt COMPONENTS QtXml REQUIRED)

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QT_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QT_USE_FILE})

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${QT_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS} ${QT_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (find_relation_1 find_relation_1.cpp)
target_link_libraries (find_relation_1 ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries (find_relation_1 opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_video ${EXTERNAL_LIBS} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTXML_LIBRARY})
```

I had no problems and my program was running successfully after "cmake .." and "make".
Then I changed the name of the folder which my program:"find_relation_1.cpp" and its cmakelist: "CmakeList.txt" were in that. This time after writing cmake .. in the Terminal I received this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "4.8.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1171 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Then I changed the name of the folder to its previous name while I had no problem but still this message is appeared after writing "cmake .." when I want to run my program.  What is the reason for this error?

Comment: CMake stores various variables, including path informations, in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt`. Renaming either the source or the binary directory can play merry hell with that. Have you tried deleting the binary directory and attempting a clean build?

Comment: Yes, I did it but still same problem!

Comment: Did you remove the complete set of files generated by `cmake` or just the `CMakeCache.txt`?

Comment: I deleted build folder, totally and then make a new build folder and tried to run my problem, but the problem was not solved

Comment: There are some parameters of cmake. You can use them.  --debug-output               = Put cmake in a debug mode.
  --trace                      = Put cmake in trace mode.
  --trace-expand               = Put cmake in trace mode with variable

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?